# Dynamically injecting SVG filters and applying to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, svg-filters

I'm playing around with applying SVG filters to HTML. This works if everything's hard coded, although I need the `-webkit-filter` CSS id for chrome. When attempting to create an SVG element with a filter dynamically with javascript it fails. Can anyone explain why?

Here's what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/H3UX8/1/

The first image and text pair are blurred on chrome and firefox but the second pair are not.

The extract doesn't work:

```
.dynamic div {
    -webkit-filter: url('#f2');
    filter: url('#f2');
}

...

var svg = document.createElement("svg");
var filter = document.createElement("filter");
filter.setAttribute("id", "f2");
var blur = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "feGaussianBlur");
blur.setAttribute("stdDeviation", "5");
filter.appendChild(blur);
svg.appendChild(filter);
document.body.appendChild(svg);

...

<div class="dynamic">
    <div><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png" /></div>
    <div>HELLO WORLD TWO</div>
</div>
```

The html syntax looks identical. I'm guessing either `document.createElement` doesn't create svg capable tags or maybe the filter IDs are only read once on document load. I *can*, however, dynamically change the value of `stdDeviation` in the static example.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
var NS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var svg = document.createElementNS( NS, "svg" );

var filter = document.createElementNS( NS, "filter" );
filter.setAttribute( "id", "f2" );

var blur = document.createElementNS( NS, "feGaussianBlur" );
blur.setAttribute( "stdDeviation", "5" );

filter.appendChild( blur );
svg.appendChild( filter );
document.body.appendChild( svg );
```

Comment: Works straight away, thanks! Can you explain or post a link explaining why I need the *namespace URI* version of the call?

Comment: If you don't put the SVG elements in the SVG namespace then they end up in the default (HTML) namespace and are not recognised by the SVG parser.